# How to draw a fitting circle around nodes in tikz-qtree?

Tags: tikz-trees, linguistics, tikz-qtree

I'm trying to draw a circle around the final node: 
[image]

Here is what I've tried:

```
\usepackage{qtree}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree-compat}
\usepackage{xytree}
\usepackage{tikz-dependency}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{gb4e}    

  \begin{tikzpicture}[every tree node/.style={align=center,anchor=north}]
    \Tree[.CP {} [.C\1 C 
    [.TP \qroof{Stacey}.DP{\textsubscript{i}} [.T\1 T\\did 
    [.VP $t_i$ [.V\1 V\\{$\bm{\varnothing}$}\textsubscript{ACTIVE} 
    [.VP {} [.V\1 V\\break \node[draw,circle]{\qroof{what}.DP}; ] ] ] ] ] ] ] ] 
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

But this results in:

[image]

How do I stop the 'DP', triangle, and 'what' from separating and make the circle nice-fitting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reduce `inner sep`. I also made your code compile by loading the packages it is using.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree-compat}
\usepackage{bm,amssymb} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every tree node/.style={align=center,anchor=north}]
    \Tree[.CP {} [.C\1 C 
    [.TP \qroof{Stacey}.DP{\textsubscript{i}} [.T\1 T\\did 
    [.VP $t_i$ [.V\1 V\\{$\bm{\varnothing}$}\textsubscript{ACTIVE} 
    [.VP {} [.V\1 V\\break \node[draw,circle,inner sep=0pt]{\qroof{what}.DP}; ] ] ] ] ] ] ] ] 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]